# Show that the following function is having antiderivative.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following function $$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}
\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\text{ if }x\neq 0\\ 
0&\text{ if }x=0
\end{cases}\end{array}$$ and I need to show that this function has a antiderivative. How do I do that?

Comment: Continuous a.e. and bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$Then$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}\cos\left(\frac1x\right)-2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0,\end{cases}$$which the sum of your function with a continuous function. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @OvyOvy If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Need to wait 6 minutes before I can do that.